# DatePicker control inside a devexpress grid is not loading(working)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, devexpress, devexpress-mvc

I have a partial view which consists of a devexpress grid. On clicking the edit of the respective row of the grid comes a panel where the controls to edit the values are provided. 
One among those controls is a datepicker. This date picker's calender control does not load to allow me to select a date. Instead the from and to date controls remain as textboxes.
Below is my code for the partial.

```
@{

    var grid = Html.DevExpress().GridView(settings =>
    {
        settings.Name = "GridViewDuration";
        settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "DurationMaster", Action = "GridViewDurationPartial" };

        settings.SettingsEditing.AddNewRowRouteValues = new { Controller = "MyController", Action = "MyControllerAction1" };
        settings.SettingsEditing.UpdateRowRouteValues = new { Controller = "MyController", Action = "MyControllerAction2" };
        settings.SettingsEditing.DeleteRowRouteValues = new { Controller = "MyController", Action = "MyControllerAction3" };
        settings.SettingsEditing.Mode = GridViewEditingMode.EditFormAndDisplayRow;
        settings.SettingsBehavior.ConfirmDelete = true;

        settings.CommandColumn.Visible = true;
        settings.CommandColumn.ShowNewButton = true;
        settings.CommandColumn.ShowDeleteButton = true;
        settings.CommandColumn.ShowEditButton = true;

        settings.KeyFieldName = "DurationId";

        settings.SettingsPager.Visible = true;
        settings.SettingsPager.PageSize = 20;
        settings.Settings.ShowGroupPanel = true;
        settings.Settings.ShowFilterRow = true;
        settings.SettingsBehavior.AllowSelectByRowClick = false;
        settings.Columns.Add(column =>
        {
            column.FieldName = "Column1";
            column.ReadOnly = true;
            column.Width = 20;

        });
        settings.Columns.Add(column =>
        {
            column.FieldName = "Column2";
            column.Caption = "xyz";
            column.ColumnType = MVCxGridViewColumnType.ComboBox;
            column.Width = 250;

            var comboBoxProperties = column.PropertiesEdit as ComboBoxProperties;
            comboBoxProperties.DataSource = PMC.Web.Controllers.DurationMasterController.getSelectList("0", "MyAction4");
            comboBoxProperties.TextField = "Text";
            comboBoxProperties.ValueField = "Value";
            comboBoxProperties.ValueType = typeof(int);
            comboBoxProperties.ValidationSettings.RequiredField.IsRequired = true;


        });
        settings.InitNewRow = (sender, e) =>
        {
            e.NewValues["ColumnId"] = 0;
        };
        settings.Columns.Add("ColumnName");
        settings.Columns.Add("Description");
        //settings.Columns.Add("DisplayName");
        settings.Columns.Add("FromDate");
        settings.Columns.Add("ToDate");
    });
    if (ViewData["EditError"] != null)
    {
        grid.SetEditErrorText((string)ViewData["EditError"]);
    }

}
@grid.Bind(Model).GetHtml()
```

And Below is my view which render the above partial and also consists the javascript code to load the datepicker's calender control

```
@model List<XYZ.Data.ViewModel.Admin.MyModel>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "XYZ";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/UserManagementScript.js")'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        debugger
        $("#GridViewDuration_DXEditor5_I").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            gotoCurrent: true,
            minDate: '01/01/2015',
            maxDate: new Date(),
            constrainInput: false,
            selectMonths: '12',
            selectYears: '30',
            duration: ''
        });

        $("#GridViewDuration_DXEditor6_I").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            gotoCurrent: true,
            minDate: '01/01/2015',
            maxDate: new Date(),
            constrainInput: false,
            selectMonths: '12',
            selectYears: '30',
            duration: ''

        });
    });

    document.getElementById("GridViewDuration_DXCBtn0").addEventListener("click", function () {
        debugger
        $("#GridViewDuration_DXEditor5_I").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            gotoCurrent: true,
            minDate: '01/01/2015',
            maxDate: new Date(),
            constrainInput: false,
            selectMonths: '12',
            selectYears: '30',
            duration: ''
        });

        $("#GridViewDuration_DXEditor6_I").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            gotoCurrent: true,
            minDate: '01/01/2015',
            maxDate: new Date(),
            constrainInput: false,
            selectMonths: '12',
            selectYears: '30',
            duration: ''

        });
    });

    //$('#GridViewDuration_DXCBtn0').click(function () {
    //    debugger
    //    $("#GridViewDuration_DXEditor5_I").datepicker({
    //        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
    //        changeMonth: true,
    //        changeYear: true,
    //        gotoCurrent: true,
    //        minDate: '01/01/2015',
    //        maxDate: new Date(),
    //        constrainInput: false,
    //        selectMonths: '12',
    //        selectYears: '30',
    //        duration: ''
    //    });

    //    $("#GridViewDuration_DXEditor6_I").datepicker({
    //        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
    //        changeMonth: true,
    //        changeYear: true,
    //        gotoCurrent: true,
    //        minDate: '01/01/2015',
    //        maxDate: new Date(),
    //        constrainInput: false,
    //        selectMonths: '12',
    //        selectYears: '30',
    //        duration: ''

    //    });
    //});

</script>


    @Html.Partial("_Common")

    @Html.DevExpress().GetStyleSheets(

    new StyleSheet { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.GridView }
)
    @Html.DevExpress().GetScripts(

    new Script { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.GridView }
)



    @Html.Partial("_GridViewDurationPartial", Model)
```

And here is how it looks, 
[image: OnPageLoad]

And here it is when edited

[image: OEditClick]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this workaround:

Add a css class your columns

```
settings.Columns.Add(column =>
{
    column.FieldName = "FromDate";
    column.Caption = "FromDate";
    column.CellStyle.CssClass = "datepicker";
});
settings.Columns.Add(column =>
{
    column.FieldName = "ToDate";
    column.Caption = "ToDate";
    column.CellStyle.CssClass = "datepicker";
});
```

And bind your datepicker to that css class

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        gotoCurrent: true,
        minDate: '01/01/2015',
        maxDate: new Date(),
        constrainInput: false,
        selectMonths: '12',
        selectYears: '30',
        duration: ''

    });
```

This is not tested but it should work.

Comment: Please make sure that you don't have errors in browser console, then inspect your input textbox and make sure that it has that class (if it hasn't adapt the jQuery selector). If all this is ok and still not working then try to init the datepicker directly from browser console ( just to test ) , a line like this `$("[your selector]").datepiker();` is enough for test. If this last attempt is not working then for sure your problem is somewhere else. I am sure that this should work because I have used similar solutions before.